# DFS Algorithm - 8-Puzzle or nXn-Game

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to solve an DFS algorithm. It is about the game `8-puzzles` or `N x N` puzzle. At the beginning i have two arrays like (the Zero represents an empty field):

```
int[][] start = {{0,1,2}, {4,5,3}, {7,8,6}};
int[][] target = {{1,2,3}, {1,5,6}, {7,8,0}};
```

This arrays goes into my generic DFS class, which works fine. I used it of other tasks correctly. But for the completeness here is the `basic` part of my DFS class:

```
private static boolean search(State node, State target) {
    if (node.equals(target))
        return true;

    for (State neighbour : node.getNeighbours()) {
        if (!visited.contains(neighbour)) {
            predMap.put(neighbour,node);
            visited.add(neighbour);
            if (search(neighbour, target)){
              return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So at first my `start` array will pass as the first parameter and my `target` array as the second.

In my `State`class i want to implement the `getNeighbours()`method which should return all possibles states. In the first Round something like:

```
First:
|0|1|2|
|4|5|3|
|7|8|6|

Second (rotated zero):
|1|0|2|
|4|5|3|
|7|8|6|

etc...
```

And here is my problem. How can u do that? It works for the first 4 operations but then i get an exception (The zero or the empty field is not on the position as excepted or there are two zeros). What is wrong there?

```
@Override
public List<State> getNeighbours() {
    List<State> neighbours = new LinkedList<>();

    // possibles moves...
    final int startX = (freeX - 1 < 0) ? freeX : freeX - 1;
    final int startY = (freeY - 1 < 0) ? freeY : freeY - 1;
    final int endX = (freeX + 1 > N - 1) ? freeX : freeX + 1;
    final int endY = (freeY + 1 > N - 1) ? freeY : freeY + 1;

    for (int row = startX; row <= endX; row++) {
        for (int column = startY; column <= endY; column++) {
            int tmp = board[row][column];
            board[row][column] = board[freeX][freeY];
            board[freeX][freeY] = tmp;

            // Just show the table...
            System.out.println("=== BEFORE ===");
            for (int[] x : board) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
            }

            neighbours.add(new State(board, freeX + row, freeY + column));

            board[freeX][freeY] = board[row][column];
            board[row][column] = tmp;

            // Just show the table...
            System.out.println("=== AFTER ===");
            for (int[] x : board) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
            }
        }
    }

    return neighbours;    
}
```

complete code https://gist.github.com/T0bbes/66d36326aa8878d5961880ce370ba82d

Comment: Could you please post all your code out? Or a url of github repo?

Comment: Sure. I edited my post. At the end is a link

Comment: The code of state is not given in that gist..

Comment: It's just an interface but i updated the gist

Comment: Please take a look at my answer... If you still have questions, please feel free to leave a comment...

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, the reason of get that exception is, the board array is shared by every state. You should make a deep copy of that array, and you can try this code:

```
public Board(int[][] board, int x, int y){
    if (board[x][y]!=0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Field (" +x+","+y+") must be free (0).");
    this.board = new int[board.length][board[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.board.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < this.board[i].length; j++)
            this.board[i][j] = board[i][j];
    this.freeX = x;
    this.freeY = y;
    this.N = board.length;
}
```

But there are still some problems in your code:

1. DFS may recursion a lot and get a StackOverflow -- you should increase stack size(`-Xss100m` works for me). After increase stack size, your code can output a solution, but it takes 197144 steps...
2. Indeed, as you see, DFS output only a valid solution(if your code is correct), not optimal solution. You should try BFS.